# Is it OK to have a many-to-many relationship where one of the tables involved is already a junction table?

Tags: database, database-design, patterns-and-practices, relational-database

When planning our database, we ended up with a setup like this:

We have `Company`, `Product` and `Person`.

There is a many-to-many relationship between `Company` and `Product`, through a junction table `Company_Product`, because a given company may produce more than one product (such as "car" and "bicycle"), but also a given product, such as "car", can be produced by multiple companies. In the junction table `Company_Product` there is an extra field "price" which is the price in which the given company sells the given product.

There is another many-to-many relationship between `Company_Product` and `Person`, through a junction table `Company_Product_Person`. Yes, it is a many-to-many relationship involving one entity that is already a junction table. This is because a Person can own multiple products, such as a car from company1 and a bicycle from company2, and in turn the same company_product can be owned by more than one person, since for example both person1 and person2 could have bought a car from company1. In the junction table `Company_Product_Person` there is an extra field "thoughts" which contains the thoughts of the person at the moment they purchased the company_product.

**Is this commonly-acceptable or is this a sign that something is wrong? If it's weird, what would be a better solution?**

I've been running into a few problems with this ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48713019/4135063)), so I was wondering, perhaps my database setup is wrong to begin with.

Comment: Few things in software development are actually "standard;" the C# specification is one of them (it being an ECMA standard).  Did you really mean "commonly-accepted?"

Comment: Your database schema seems reasonable.  The JSON arrangement you came up with looks like a "reporting" problem to me (i.e. it is constructed output).  You just need to create the correct logic to construct it.  The only reason you might have trouble is if you want it to be reversible; that is, to reconstruct the original entities from the resulting JSON.  But even then, you have all the Id's.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the fast reply. I am not sure I follow your reasoning, what exactly is a "reporting problem"? As I mention in my linked question, I am looking for the "right way" to do it (because I already have in mind a very inefficient way, both in memory and time, so I was wondering if sequelize can do it or not). But that's a discussion for the linked question, not this one. If you can expand your last comment in an answer here, that would be great. (continued)

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I understand correctly, you're basically saying that "it seems to be acceptable", although the fact that you needed the real-life example to think more about it is an evidence that it is not "clearly acceptable at the first glance".

Comment: No, it's evidence that one can't make a reasonable judgement without more specifics.  It's like asking how many numbers one should put on a dice if one doesn't know how many sides the dice has.

Comment: As to the JSON, part of why I called it a "reporting problem" is that you can make the JSON output look any way you like, so long as it serves your purposes.  The real issue is the database schema, and that looks solid to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you're right, I may have made a bad choice of words. What I meant is that such a scheme indeed isn't super common (although admittedly I see now that such conclusion isn't much useful by itself anyway :P)

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's great, thanks! If you could join your comments in an answer here I would be happy to upvote (and we might even clear the comments later) :)

Answer (score 5):

In making the logical design of your database, you should not think in terms of "junction tables", but in terms of relations.

Your first "junction table" seems to correspond to the relation "*Company* sells *Product* for *Price*". Your second "junction table" seems to correspond to the relation "*Person* owns *Product* manufactured by *Company*".

While it would depend on the full context, I'd likely model the second relation as a table with foreign keys to the `Company`, `Product`, and `Person` tables and with no connection to the other "junction table". This raises the risk that I could claim that a person owns a product that was never manufactured by a company, but it also allows deleting a row from the "sells product" table without losing all the ownership information for anybody that happened to own that product from that company. Maybe this isn't an issue for you, in which case this isn't a reason not to structure the tables in the way you suggest, and the risk I mentioned before *is* a reason to structure the tables in the way you suggest.

More generally, what I would recommend (besides thinking relationally rather than in terms of "tables" and "junction tables") is to consider what happens as things change. For example, let's say you want to calculate how much a person has spent on various products. If the prices can change, then you can't do this with your suggested representation (nor my suggestion without adding additional information), since the person may have bought the product at a time when the price was different. Temporal database techniques can handle these situations generally, but fully doing this is often overkill. Nevertheless, I recommend looking at temporal databases as they tend to more accurately model the situation. From there you can consider what data (if any) is unimportant and thus you can lose. (Temporal databases are usually "insert-only".) I suspect if you factor in how the data can change over time, you will want a schema different from your original suggestion and my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have a junction between 2 tables (`AB`), and then between them and yet another table (`ABC`).

We can say that `AB` may be a much smaller relation, so it can be kept in RAM, while `ABC` is huge and won't fit. So queries touching `AB` would be faster that queries to `ABC`. A separate index on just `A` and `B` fields on `ABC` would still be much larger than an index on unique `AB` pairs.

OTOH I would not make `ABC` depend on `AB` for a FK; instead I'd make it depend on `A`, `B`, and `C` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As for your last sentence, don't I lose some information by doing that? In my situation, both junction tables mentioned in my question have other important fields (not only the IDs), and if I follow your suggestion of a making ABC depend on A, B, and C directly, looks like I can't store the extraField that existed in AB anymore. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Welcome. Why, of course you can store extra fields: `create table ABC (a_id, b_id, c_id, extra_field, foreign key (a_id) references A(id),...)`. The idea is that you reference `A` and `B` directly for FKs, not `AB`.

Comment: I've updated my question, please take a look. I wonder that if I create a table as you're suggesting, I can't store the "price" field in any meaningful way anymore (or perhaps I'm missing something, hopefully(?)). Thanks again.

Comment: I upvote and endorse the answer by @derek-elkins above.

Answer (score 1):

OP here.

After reading the provided answers and further researching and thinking about the subject, I concluded that there's nothing technically wrong with my setup *per se*. However, since I was facing a practical problem with it, I found a solution that consisted in reworking a bit the relationships in my scheme. I don't know if my difficulties were specific to the JavaScript ORM I was using (namely [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)) or would exist in other ORMs as well, but regardless, I found a different setup that also makes sense and avoids this problem.

Thus, I decided to post my own answer here too, so that if anyone stumbles in a similar situation, perhaps altering the scheme as I did will help (although the original scheme isn't technically wrong).

Quoting [my own answer to my linked question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813935/4135063):

> #### Analyzing the old approach
>
> First of all, both junction tables given in my question were more than "just" junction tables. They weren't simply a tool to define which elements were related to which elements, but they were something more:
>
> - They also had extra information (the fields "price" and "thoughts", respectively);
> - The first one, `Company_Product`, also had relationships with other tables itself.
>
> This is not technically wrong, strictly speaking, but there is a more natural way to structure the database to represent the same things. And better, with this new approach, making the query I want becomes very simple.
>
> #### Solution: new approach
>
> The solution rises when we see that we are modeling items that can be purchased and the purchases themselves. Instead of keeping this information "disguised" inside the junction table of a many-to-many relationship, we shall have them as explicit entities in our scheme, with their own tables.
>
> So, first, to clarify, let's rename our models:
>
> - `Company` stays `Company`
> - `Product` becomes `ProductType`
> - `Company_Product` becomes `Product`
> - `Person` stays `Person`
> - `Company_Product_Person` becomes `Purchase`
>
> And then we see that:
>
> - A `Product` has one `Company` and one `ProductType`. Conversely, the same `Company` can be related to multiple `Product` and the same `ProductType` can be related to multiple `Product`.
> - A `Purchase` has one `Product` and one `Person`. Conversely, the same `Product` can be related to multiple `Purchase` and the same `Product` can be related to multiple `Person`.
>
> Note that there are no many-to-many relationships anymore.
>
> [...]
>
> Instead of using junction tables that were more than simple junction tables, we got rid of the many-to-many relationships and "promoted" the junction tables to full-fledged entities of our scheme. In fact, the tables are the same; the changes were only in the relations and in the way to look at them.